# Add CSS class to dynamic ul li a tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-selectors

I have a list of ul li in div on which I want to add CSS classes based on click on a tag.

Here is my html of ul li:

```
<div class="tabs1">
    <ul>
       <li class="active"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="change_program()" class="program active" title="Program"></a></li>
       <li><a href="javascript:;" onclick="change_sd()" class="sd" title="Discriminative Stimulus"></a></li>
       <li><a href="javascript:;" onclick="change_response()" class="response" title="Response"></a></li>
       <li><a href="javascript:;" onclick="change_enforces()" class="enforces" title="Reinforcers"></a></li>
       <li><a href="javascript:;" onclick="change_sro()" class="sro" title="Short Range Objective"></a></li>
       <li><a href="javascript:;" onclick="change_lro()" class="lro" title="Long Range Objective"></a></li>
       <li><a href="javascript:;" onclick="change_prompt()" class="prompt" title="Prompt"></a></li>
     </ul>
  </div>
```

Here are the functions that are calling on these a tags:

```
function change_program(){ 
    document.getElementById("program").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("bcs_sub").style.display="block";
    document.getElementById("trial").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("sd").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("graphs").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("summary").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("response").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("enforces").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("sro").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("lro").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("prompt").style.display="none";

}
function change_sd(){
    document.getElementById("sd").style.display="block";
    document.getElementById("program").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("trial").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("bcs_sub").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("graphs").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("summary").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("response").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("enforces").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("sro").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("lro").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("prompt").style.display="none";
}
function change_response(){
    document.getElementById("response").style.display="block";
    document.getElementById("sd").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("trial").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("program").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("bcs_sub").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("graphs").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("summary").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("enforces").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("sro").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("lro").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("prompt").style.display="none";
}
function change_enforces(){
    document.getElementById("enforces").style.display="block";
    document.getElementById("response").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("sd").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("trial").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("program").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("bcs_sub").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("graphs").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("summary").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("sro").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("lro").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("prompt").style.display="none";
}   
function change_sro(){
    document.getElementById("sro").style.display="block";
    document.getElementById("enforces").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("response").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("sd").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("trial").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("program").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("bcs_sub").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("graphs").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("summary").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("lro").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("prompt").style.display="none";
}
function change_lro(){

    document.getElementById("lro").style.display="block";
    document.getElementById("enforces").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("response").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("sd").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("trial").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("program").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("bcs_sub").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("graphs").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("summary").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("sro").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("prompt").style.display="none";
}
function change_prompt(){
    document.getElementById("prompt").style.display="block";
    document.getElementById("enforces").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("response").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("sd").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("trial").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("program").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("bcs_sub").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("graphs").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("summary").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("sro").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("lro").style.display="none";
}
```

I simply want to do this operation of adding classes in these functions using javascript.

CSS class for all a tags are:

```
<style>
.tabs1 ul li a.program:active {
  width: 129px;
  background: url(../images/program_steps_h.png) no-repeat;
}
.tabs1 ul li a.sd:active {
  width: 129px;
  background: url(../images/program_steps_sd.png) no-repeat;
}
.tabs1 ul li a.response:active {
  width: 129px;
  background: url(../images/program_steps_response.png) no-repeat;
}
.tabs1 ul li a.enforces:active {
  width: 129px;
  background: url(../images/program_steps_enforces.png) no-repeat;
}
.tabs1 ul li a.sro:active {
  width: 129px;
  background: url(../images/program_steps_sro.png) no-repeat;
}
.tabs1 ul li a.lro:active {
  width: 129px;
  background: url(../images/program_steps_lro.png) no-repeat;
}
.tabs1 ul li a.prompt:active {
  width: 129px;
  background: url(../images/program_steps_prompt.png) no-repeat;
}
</style>
```

Comment: As an aside, you should really look to DRY that code up.

Comment: Well, seriously I don't like that sort of coding either as that project is developed since 2006. I have a task from some one whom I am struggling to get this done. @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: `:active` is not a class, it's a [pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes). I'm confused, do you want to add `:active` or `.active` to the elements?

Comment: @MuhammadMohsin ok, if you can add more of your HTML (namely the elements which are referenced by `id` in your JS code) then I can help you.

Comment: Sorry, I want to add `.active` to the element only. @RGraham

Comment: I am sorry its a bunch of HTML that have only tables and ids combination. I want to keep things simple. Is it really necessary? @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you mean this:

```
$(function () { // on load of page
    // on a click on any link in the UL
    $("div.tabs1>ul>li>a").on("click", function (e) { 
        e.preventDefault(); // cancel click
        // remove all active from all elements under UL
        $(this).closest("ul").find(".active").removeClass("active"); 
        // add active to the clicked
        $(this).addClass("active");
        // add active to the clicked's parent LI 
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");
        // hide all target divs
        $(".toggleDiv").hide();
        // show the one with ID= contents of data-target of clicked link
        $("#"+$(this).data("target")).show();
    }).first().click(); // click the first on load
});
```

using

```
<div class="tabs1">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" data-target="program" class="program" title="Program">Program</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-target="sd" class="sd" title="Discriminative Stimulus">SD</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-target="response" class="response" title="Response">Response</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-target="enforces" class="enforces" title="Reinforcers">Enforces</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-target="sro" class="sro" title="Short Range Objective">SRO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-target="lro" class="lro" title="Long Range Objective">LRO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-target="prompt" class="prompt" title="Prompt">PROMPT</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="sro" class="toggleDiv">SRO....</div>
<div id="sd" class="toggleDiv">SD...</div>
```

```js
$(function () {
    $("div.tabs1>ul>li>a").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // cancel click
        $(this).closest("ul").find(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");
        $(".toggleDiv").hide();
        $("#"+$(this).data("target")).show();
    }).first().click(); // click the first on load
});
```

```css
.toggleDiv { display:none }
li.active { background-color:red } 
.active { color:yellow }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs1">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" data-target="program" class="program" title="Program">Program</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-target="sd" class="sd" title="Discriminative Stimulus">SD</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-target="response" class="response" title="Response">Response</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-target="enforces" class="enforces" title="Reinforcers">Enforces</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-target="sro" class="sro" title="Short Range Objective">SRO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-target="lro" class="lro" title="Long Range Objective">LRO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-target="prompt" class="prompt" title="Prompt">PROMPT</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="sro" class="toggleDiv">SRO....</div>
<div id="sd" class="toggleDiv">SD...</div>
```

Comment: it says: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` for `$("div.tabs1>ul>li>a").on("click", function () {` @mplungjan

Comment: You need to include jQuery too

Comment: Can you please add comments to your code so I will understand how the code is working please? @mplungjan

Comment: Can we select and make active `program` one by default on page load? @mplungjan

Comment: Thank you very much for your all help and perfect solution. It is perfectly working for me without any problem. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't add pseudo-classes to elements, only real classes. pseudo-classes represent changes in the state of the browser, e.g. `:hover` when the mouse is over the element.

So instead of selectors like `.tabs1 ul li a.prompt:active` you should use `.tabs1 ul li a.prompt.active`. Then you can use the jQuery:

```
$(selector).addClass("active");
```

to add the class to some elements.

Comment: Thank you. What actually will be the jquery function for this? Is there any function necessary? @barmar

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. This is the jQuery function. You would call it in your `change_XX` functions.

Comment: I understood what you wanted to say. :) thank you that helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this :

```
<p id = "go-for-it">Hi !</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("go-for-it").className = "hi-buddy";
</script>
```

Comment: No. That will REPLACE any classes. At least use a classList